# Is there any npm library that can avoid getting blocked when web scraping

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, dom

I'm making and android application that shows some results from Amazon. The app makes a request to a custom Express server that returns amazon results in a JSON via web scrapping (for example, https://www.amazon.com/s?k=nike). My server worked fine, but now it returns empty array. The exact same code works on my laptop, so I supose I'm getting blocked by amazon domain.
I know some things that i could make: change ip, crawl slowler, use proxies, rotate user agents, blablabla...
Is there any npm library that can avoid getting blocked when web scrapping? Maybe selenium?

For your information, i'm using the npm web scrapping module : [unofficial-amazon-search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unofficial-amazon-search)

Comment: What is your scrapping rate at the time they blocked you? 10 a day? 100, 1K, 10K a day? Is it the same URL with different search params? No other url? Have you tried to contact them to know the reason of the block, maybe they got a paid service for their search after a certain rate.

Comment: Maybe 200 req per day. Is the same url with diferent search parameters, yes. Indeed is the sample url from amazon. I searched and there are unnoficial amazon product API that offers like 100req per day free, but didn't found official amazon api, thats why im web scraping it

Comment: Yes, there is a library that can help you! Check out the [Apify SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apify). It's an open source library that handles a whole lot of the overheads that come with webscraping, such as dealing with anti-scraping measures. It automatically handles all the stuff you listed. It supports Cheerio, Puppeteer, and Playwright. You can also take the free Apify course on web scraping [here](https://developers.apify.com/academy/web-scraping-for-beginners). It's being added to daily.

Also I think I have to disclose that I work for Apify, so this is my disclosure statement.

Comment: @KeitelDOG Amazon is a tough one. Their bot detection is pretty good. With certain implementations in place, their anti-scraping measures can be circumvented.